# How to differentiate an integration?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, definite-integrals

$$\int_{q_1}^{q_2}f_T(t)dt=0.6826\ldots(1)$$

How differentiating equation $(1)$ with respect to $q_1$ yields 
$$f_T(q_2)\frac{dq_2}{dq_1}-f_T(q_1)=0$$

Comment: See [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). In your case the parameter $\theta$ should be $q_1$.

Comment: is the integrand $f(t)$ ?because in your question both question and answer contains $f_T(t)$.

Comment: @SurajM.S yes, The integrand is $f(t)$. This is actually a sampling distribution [`t- distribution` with $(n-1)$ degrees of freedom.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus you can write
$$
\int_{q_1}^{q_2} f_T(t) dt = G(q_2)-G(q_1),
$$
with $G$ an antiderivative of $f_T$, that is: $G'(t) = f_T(t)$. You thus have
$$
G(q_2)-G(q_1) = 0.6826\dots
$$
and now taking derivatives with respect to $q_2$ and using the chain rule yields the formula you want.